# Implementing 'Recently Deleted' With CoreData

Tags: core-data

I want to implement 'recently deleted' folder/section in my CoreData app (example: recently deleted folder in photos or notes app). I searched the web but couldn't find much about it.

Here's how I'm thinking of doing it:

- Adding isDeleted(bool) attribute to the entity
- Delete the object from context if more than 30 days have passed since the deletion

Is this the way to go? Are there any other ways of implementing this feature?

Comment: This question is very broad so it's hard to answer but one comment, why not make the deleted attribute a date instead of a bool so you won't need a second attribute to know when it was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that you can use to (a) tell if something should be in "recently deleted" as opposed to active non-deleted data, and (b) figure out when it's time to really delete it, will do the job.

Using a boolean flag is good for (a) but won't help with (b). For (b) you can include a date field, which as a comment notes, means you don't necessarily need the boolean. For example if you have a `deletedDate` property that's optional, regular fetches always make sure to fetch only data where `deletedDate` is nil. Then you can use the property to decide when to really delete the item.

You could also implement a computed boolean property that's `true`/`false` based on whether or not `deletedDate` is nil.

If you add a boolean property, do not under any circumstances try to call it `isDeleted`, because `NSManagedObject` already has a property with that name. Overriding it would mess with Core Data's ability to track actually-deleted objects.